# I am getting Jquery debugger error it going to stop working

Tags: jquery, javascript-framework

I using Jquery framework Jquery-1.3.2.js , 
 when I calling user defined function in every time interval ( about 5 seconds )

then I getting popup error message : 
"**A script on this page may be busy or it may have stopped responding . You can stop the script now, open the script in debugger, or let the script continue**"

error from script Jquery-1.3.2.js 
I used function as below

```
function getMore()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service/getList.asmx",
        data: "{ }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) 
        {
            if(msg  != null)
            {
                if(msg  != null)
                {
                    var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    dynDiv.id = "divDyna";
                    dynDiv.innerHTML = msg;
                    document.getElementById('Div1').appendChild(dynDiv);
                    $('div#Div1').slideDown();   
                }              
            }
        }        
    });     
}
```

**`How I can solve it or handle error ( if possible in try catch ) ?`**

see the attached screen shot [image].

Comment: In this case this error occurs either when you keep calling setInterval by mistake thus pilling up a process after a process. Or it falls in an infite loop. Or the results are delivered slower than are being asked again.

Comment: Hello @elasticrash , I am not used set interval function.. When I scrolled window then I calling my function for getting new list from my database and rendered it on the page. in between sometime I getting that error message about stop working Jquery.. - Thanks Abhi.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is related to calling this function too many times in a row, even when some of the calls are not ready yet.
One solution is to call getMore() to get more than 1 record at a time, for example 5 records.

Facebook does this in the NewsFeed at the end of the page automatically, but it gets like 10 records.

Comment: I get 20 record when I scrolling down I set get 20 records. user moved scrolling down fast then sometime it getting error message as shown above.. stop script.

Answer (score 0):

This happen when your script takes longer time to execute. You can increase the allowed time for script execution in firefox.
you can refer [this]: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/warning-unresponsive-script